# How to call a method on collection view all cells?

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

On long press gesture on a collectionview cell I want to do some animation on all collectionview cells.
How to achieve that?
One way is to reload the collectionview. I am just curious is there another way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you use notifications?

In your `UICollectionViewCell` initialization code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doFancyAnimation:) name:@"MyNotification" object:nil];
```

And then from your gesture recognizer, post a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyNotification" object:self];
```

Comment: Yeah sounds great. But i observed only visible cells are caring about the notifications. And while I scroll the animation stops because of reusing of cells :-(